# PHP + Sybase ASE database connection difficulties

Tags: php, database, sybase, sap-ase

I'm developing a PHP application that needs to access a SAP Sybase ASE Database.

I'm having tremendous problems trying to connect to Sybase ASE using PHP.
I don't want to use ODBC cause I want to avoid touching and configuring my clients machine.

Is there any simple solution for connecting to Sybase ASE? 
In Java I can just download a JDBC file and the magic happens... is there any solution like this for PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the [Sybase Programmers Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01693.1570/doc/html/title.html) for the ASE PHP module, and install the [PHP Extenstion Module](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01693.1570/doc/html/car1311906440579.html) (part of the Sybase SDK)

Comment: Do I have to install the Sybase SDK on my clients machine? I can't seem to find the link to download the Sybase SDK anywhere without owning a Sybase Product.

Comment: The only PHP module avaliabe is php_sybase_ct.dll, but it requires many dependencies (libcs.dll, libct.dll and many others). I created an account in the website, yet, no download links avaliable.

Comment: http://www.sybase.com/detail_list?id=3610  - It should be part of the ASE 15.7 Developers Edition download.

Comment: Many problems during the install. Then inside the directory \Sybase\ASE-15_0 there is no .DLL that PHP requires.

Comment: ASE-15_0 is the installation directory for ASE, not the php plugin. It's most likely to be OCS-15_0  (according to the installation instructions).  I would read throught the installation instructions first, then procede.

Comment: The .DLL ones inside \Sybase\OCS\ does not work... PHP calls the sybase_connect() but nothing happens, no expections, no connection.

Comment: I need a sybase client installed event having the drivers just to have a sql.ini that points out to the remote Sybase ASE server? This is horrible. Any workaround on this?